# What's the format of a P.E.E.E.R. paragraph?

Tags: academic-writing, structure

I know most of the parts of a P.E.E.E.R. paragraph, but I'm not sure what one of the Es are, and I'm not sure how they fit together.

P is for Point, one E is for Evidence, another is for Explain. An internet search showed that the last E is Explore. R is for Restate.

How do all of the parts fit together?

Comment: This was my first Google search result: https://sites.google.com/view/year-9-english/basic-grammar/the-peer-paragraph Apparently it is called a PEER paragraphy, with one E less. My recommendation is to use a search engine first when you have a question. Often you'll find your answer there. There's also the PEEL paragraph and the PEE paragraph. Just google them.

Comment: Oh, and here is the PEEER paragraph: http://dtlomax.weebly.com/uploads/2/2/3/1/22318366/renaissance_peeer_paragraphs_1_&_2.pdf